# How to convert subprocesss.check_output() to list from string?

Tags: python, subprocess

When I run this subprocess cmd, the type returned is a string, even though there are 5 lines printed to console

```
s3_ls = subprocess.check_output(["aws", "s3", "ls", s3_loc, "-- 
recursive", "--profile", "RoleName"])

2016-11-17 23:34:45          0 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/category
2016-11-17 23:34:46          0 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.01/
2016-12-05 17:37:25     234059 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.01/entity.01.csv.gz
2016-11-17 23:34:47          0 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.02/
2016-12-05 17:37:31     109015 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.02/entity.02.csv.gz
```

How can I process this output so it's a list of 5 strings instead of just a big long one?  I tried wrapping it in list(my subprocess cmd), but that just splits everything in to a single character element.

What I want to do, is have a list of files returned after running the python subprocess cmd above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about splitting it?

```
s3_ls.split('\n')
```

Comment: I  didn't think it had newlines in it because it was type str and showed a length that wa sobviously counting chars, not lines.  So I never thought to try this.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how it was _obvious_. Try `len(s3_ls)` and compare it to `len(s3_ls.replace('\n',''))`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can change the output given by the `s3` command, but given that the output is one string. You could split it up into the filenames or entire line by doing:

```
>>> re.findall(r'dtop.+', s)
['dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/category', 'dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.01/', 'dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.01/entity.01.csv.gz', 'dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.02/', 'dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.02/entity.02.csv.gz']
```

Or:

```
>>> re.split(r'\n', s) # or s.split('\n') would be the same here
['2016-11-17 23:34:45          0 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/category', '2016-11-17 23:34:46          0 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.01/', '2016-12-05 17:37:25     234059 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.01/entity.01.csv.gz', '2016-11-17 23:34:47          0 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.02/', '2016-12-05 17:37:31     109015 dtop_dir/fldr_01/fldr_02/holding/date4y2m/entity.02/entity.02.csv.gz']
```